# Retrofit2 with generic response

Tags: android, generics, retrofit2

I have an Android App that must receive different JSONs based on an input parameter passed to the web API call. To achieve that I have created a generic Call as the following

```
@GET("GetData")
Call<Properties<T>> <T> getData(@Field("username") String userName, @Field("type") String type);
```

The class Properties has a generic variable T, that it is specified when getData is called. Everything is fine during build. But at run time I cannot get a reference to the function (null). And the internal exception says a unexpected return type has been specified.

Is there a way to make Retrofit2 work with generic response types ?

Comment: Sorry, but no generics in retrofit interfaces.
proof - https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/885

Comment: Thanks... I really do not understand why that serious limitation.